# Lookup using spring-xd

Tags: spring-xd

I am looking for way to perform lookup operation using spring-xd.

My problem statement goes like this,

I have a stream of JSON events coming in, I want to have the values of events looked-up against the threshold values in my file in HDFS or directly from RDBMS.

Please suggest a way to perform this.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you have different thresholds for different values in your messages.

Something like

value 'A' -> 100

value 'B' -> 200

...

This information is stored in a file or in a relational database. Now you want to filter the events based on their values and the corresponding thresholds.

I guess you would have to write a custom processor that holds a connection to the database where these values are stored, and queries them. If the mapping is small enough you should consider cashing it, or at least cache the most frequently used values, such that this does not slow down your stream.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can write a groovy processor to receive the payload, filter it, and then pass it to where ever you want like hdfs.

```
 stream --name --def "jdbc | groovyprocessor | hdfs" --deploy
```

In the case of batch, you will need to write a custom module.

Moha